# Calculating the Mode

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return, mode

I am trying to write a method that will calculate the mode of a set of data and return it. If there is no mode or more than one mode (for example: if 4 & 2 returned the most amount of times) I, want the function to return Double.NaN. I was able to get the mode, but I'm having trouble making my code return Double NaN if there is more than one mode.

Here is my code!

```
public double mode() {

    if (data == null) {
        double mode;
        mode = Double.NaN;
        return mode; // returns no value if array is null
    }

    double mode = 0;
    double modeCounter = 0;

    for (int c = 0; c < data.length; ++c) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            if (data[i] == data[i])
                ++count;
        }
        if (count > modeCounter) {
            modeCounter = count;
            mode = data[c];
        }
    }
    if (!(modeCounter > 1)) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    return mode;

}
```

Comment: What is data? An array?

Comment: When will there be no mode? for an array like [1,2,3], what's the mode?

Comment: if (data[i] == data[i]) - That's always true

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using Java.

We can find mode (along with the restrictions that you place to return `Double.NaN`) by simply creating a `Map` in which keys are the individual data points and the values are their corresponding count in the data array.

`Stream`s will be superuseful to write readable and succinct code.

If you have count of every member in your array/ArrayList, you can simply use this count to draw conclusions based on your requirement.

See the following code that implements the above explanation:

```
public static Double mode(List<Double> data) {
    if (data.isEmpty()) {
        // returning NaN if the input arraylist is empty 
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    Map<Double, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
    data.forEach(
            i -> {
                count.putIfAbsent(i, 1);
                count.put(i, count.get(i) + 1);
            }
    );
    int maxCount = count.values().stream().max(Integer::compare).get(); // this assumes that the data is not empty
    if (count.values().stream().filter(i -> i == maxCount).count() > 1) {
        // more than one mode present
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    // here we'll be sure that only one mode exists
    return count
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == maxCount)
            .findFirst() // as we've only one mode
            .get()
            .getKey();
}
```